# iOS alpha value of imageView failing comparison

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimageview

Here's my code:

```
#define kDeselected .3
#define kSelected 1

- (void) selectButton:(UIImageView*)iconView{
    [iconView setAlpha:kDeselected];
    if(iconView.alpha == kDeselected){
        [iconView setAlpha:kSelected];
    }
    else if(iconView.alpha == kSelected){
        [iconView setAlpha:kDeselected];
     }
}
```

I'm a pretty advanced programmer but it's beyond me as to why right before the if statement, when I manually went in and ensured that the if statement would result to true, it still doesn't hit it.

It should be noted that when kDeselected = .5, then it works perfectly. When it's .3 however...it doesn't like me.

Comment: check for rounding errors. its better to just use a bool for checking selection, and set then the alpha based on the state we are in, and not checking the alpha to determine the state

Comment: Hmmm interesting. Any ideas as to why it works with one value and not for the other though? Would it be because of some strange rounding errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting your const to a float value as `#define kDeselected 0.3f`

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is some limited precision in the storage of alpha in the iconView. It's probably returning 0.3334. Or thereabouts.

In image editing, it's rare to see an alpha value outside an 8-bit integer range. In fact, I don't think I've ever seen one.

I tried

```
    for (int i = 0; i <100; i++) {
        double myAlpha = 0.3 + i * 0.01;
        self.view.alpha = myAlpha;
        NSLog(@"myAlpha=%30.20f viewAlpha=%30.20f", myAlpha, self.view.alpha);
    }
```

and saw

```
myAlpha=        0.29999999999999998890 viewAlpha=        0.30000001192092895508
myAlpha=        0.30999999999999999778 viewAlpha=        0.31000000238418579102
myAlpha=        0.32000000000000000666 viewAlpha=        0.31999999284744262695
myAlpha=        0.32999999999999996003 viewAlpha=        0.33000001311302185059
myAlpha=        0.33999999999999996891 viewAlpha=        0.34000000357627868652
```

so expecting the returned value of alpha to be anything other than an approximation looks like wishful thinking!

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to a compiler problem when casting your constant into a type

Try doing

```
CGFloat deselectedValue = kDeselected;
```

and see what it's value actually is, and try working with that:

```
- (void) selectButton:(UIImageView*)iconView{
    CGFloat deselectedValue = kDeselected;
    [iconView setAlpha:deselectedValue];
    if(iconView.alpha == deselectedValue){
        [iconView setAlpha:deselectedValue];
    }
    else if(iconView.alpha == kSelected){
        [iconView setAlpha:kDeselected];
    }
}
```

Your other option is to try and define your .3 as `#define kDeselected 0.3f`, however I doubt it'll make a difference if .5 works